# Click tracking for links inside a SSJS Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, ssjs

I are currently having issues with click tracking for certain links in emails. In my email I have a SSJS script that parses the JSON data it get from an MC Personalization triggered campaign and saves it to an AMPscript variable-- within this, I generate links dynamically (as each product has a different URL) and append UTM parameters. I then declare the AMPscript variable in an HTML block to generate the HTML. The links generated within this SSJS script are not being tracked for clicks but other links that are present within the email are being tracked.

I've also test-sent an email with a product URL with UTM parameters linked normally to a text block and that click was tracked, so I don't think the link itself is incorrectly written. Is there a way to enable click tracking for those links generated within the SSJS script?

Comment: I believe you are going to have to use httpgetwrap like <a href="httpgetwrap|--product_link--">',

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that